# Select elements of certain depth of particular tag

Tags: css, css-selectors

In this contrived, simplified example, how could I find all `<span>` tags that are of depth 2 in terms of spans (i.e. all spans that have exactly 1 span ancestor)?

```
<span> 
    <strong>
        <span>
            <span>Hi</span>
        </span>
    </strong>
    <span>Hey</span>
</span>
```

The question is, what selector would select the second and last span only?